# Major memory usage issues with Prawn on JRuby

Tags: memory, jruby, prawn, jrubyonrails, torquebox

We've been having serious memory usage issues when compiling large documents (several hundred pages+) using Prawn with JRuby on Rails and Torquebox.

Our app basically allows users to upload a bunch of PDF documents and collates them into one. The Prawn part takes a list of files, loops over each of them page-by-page, inserts each page into our output document via `document.start_new_page(template: 'filename')` and makes some minor additions (drawing page numbers and tabs) to each page after inserting it. Some of the relevant code is copied below.

Although some of the files we're generating are fairly large, the memory usage still seems way out of proportion. For example, generating a 38MB file took over 4GB of RAM (!). This particular file was created by collating 30 files, with the largest two being 7MB and 5MB in size, and most being only a few 100KB - but we had to increase Java's heapsize to 5GB to prevent the server from falling over.

Should we be surprised that our memory usage is so high? Are we doing something wrong, and is there a fix? Thanks a lot.

Our server setup:

JRuby version: 1.7.4
Rails version: 4.0.0, running in production mode
Torquebox: 3.0.0
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Prawn version: 1.0.0rc2
JAVA_OPTS: -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms512m -Xmx5000m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

Here's the most relevant portion of the code: `add_file()` is called once for each input file. Note there's a call to `@document.start_new_page()`, which actually inserts a new page, and then a call to `start_new_page()`, which doesn't insert a new page but does ensure that `page.dictionary.date` is correctly set. I don't know if this is relevant to our memory issue.

```
  def create_or_update_document(opts)
    if @document
      @document.start_new_page(opts)
    else
      opts[:margin] = 0
      @document = Prawn::Document.new(opts)   
      @document.font_size 12
    end
  end

  def add_file(file)
    puts "     add_file() filename=#{file['full_path']}"

    filename = file['full_path']
    num_pages = file['pagecount']

    (1..num_pages).each do |page_number|
      puts "     Adding page: #{page_number}"

      # take the page defined in file 'filename' and insert it into the 
      # @document we're building
      create_or_update_document(:template => filename, :template_page => page_number)

      # this call to start_new_page doesn't change our @document, but
      # it ensures that 'page.dictionary.data' contains the settings
      # (:Rotate, etc) from the source PDF
      start_new_page(:template => filename, :template_page => page_number)

      puts "      Page size: width=#{page_width} height=#{page_height} Rotate: #{page.dictionary.data[:Rotate]}"


      # add destination for internal links e.g. from table of contents or tabs
      @document.add_dest("page#{@current_page_number}", @document.dest_fit)

      rotation = page.dictionary.data[:Rotate]
      case rotation
      when 90
        translate_x = 0
        translate_y = -page_width
        page_number_x = page_height - RightMargin
        tab_page_height = page_width

      when 180
        translate_x = -page_width
        translate_y = -page_height
        page_number_x = page_width - RightMargin
        tab_page_height = page_height

      when 270
        translate_x = -page_height
        translate_y = 0
        page_number_x = page_height - RightMargin
        tab_page_height = page_width

      else
        translate_x = 0
        translate_y = 0
        rotation = 0
        page_number_x = page_width - RightMargin
        tab_page_height = page_height
      end

      @document.rotate(rotation, :origin => [0,0]) do
        @document.translate(translate_x,translate_y) do
          if @pack.include_tabs
            add_tabs(tab_page_height, page_number_x, @current_page_number)
          end
          @document.text_box "<font name='Georgia' size='12'>#{@current_page_number}</font>", at: [page_number_x, BottomMargin + 14], inline_format: true, width: RightMargin + 100
        end
      end

      @current_page_number = @current_page_number + 1
    end
  end
```